# Downloading a jar file from a website from a link in a website

Tags: java, php, javascript, html

I want to put a link in my website such that when someone browses to my site on a phone, he can click on the download link and download the jar file and install the application on phone. I have tried this but it is not working:
[Download mobile version](http://www.cheza.net/Cloud/mobile/cloud.jar)

The jar file is a mobile version of my web application written in java.
On a PC it is able to download but not on phone.
I will really appreciate the help.

Comment: The link you have pasted shows : Not Found Error ! Please correct it.

Answer (score 0):

Some phones won't be able to download jar files above some size from the internet unless a JAD file is used to get information about the jar file first.

Follow [this link](http://wiki.forum.nokia.com/index.php/Generate_JAD_from_JAR_file) to create a jad file from jar file